# help with this nonlinear equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

given the equations

$$ 16\pi ^2 e^{4x}=y'(x)+y^{2}(x) $$

$$ 16\pi ^2 e^{4x}=y'(x)-y^{2}(x) $$

do they have closed solutions ? or solutions in terms of known functions ?

thanks